# Cannot aggregate logs coming to Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, kibana, fluent-bit

I've got a stack that consists of Kubernetes deployment, Fluent-bit, Elasticsearch, and Kibana. I'm having trouble aggregating incoming logs in Kibana, and it seems crucial to visualize them. They're currently in string format.

Here are the details - deployment spec and logs:

```
spec:
   containers:
     - name: cont
       image: busybox:latest
       command: ['sh', '-c', 'while true; do traceroute 192.168.122.1|grep legion |cut -d " " -f 7 && sleep 7; done']

$ kubectl logs deploy/ngin -n monitoring
0.090
0.194
0.397
[..]
```

Fluent-bit config:

```
 fluent-bit.conf: |
    [SERVICE]
        Flush         5
        Log_Level     error
        Daemon        off
        Parsers_File  parsers.conf

    @INCLUDE input.conf
    @INCLUDE output.conf

  input.conf: |
    [INPUT]
        Name              tail
        Tag               kube.*
        Path              /var/log/containers/*ngi*.log
        Parser            docker
        Refresh_Interval  5

  output.conf: |
    [OUTPUT]
        Name            es
        Match           *
        Host            elasticsearch
        Index           test
        Generate_ID     On
  parsers.conf: |
    [PARSER]
        Name        docker
        Format      json
        Time_Key    time
        Time_Format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L
        Time_Keep   On
        CSV_Field   value:number
```

Logs coming to Kibana and info:

[image: Logs coming to Kibana]

[image: Log cannot be aggregated]

Log cannot be aggregated.